# SVN checkout fails with “chunk delimiter was invalid”

Tags: apache, svn, openssl, visualsvn

## ERRORS:

When checking out a large project we receive error on a random file in the project:

> - Could not read response body: SSL error:  decryption failed or bad record mac

Response was to disable SSL and restarted SVNServer.

Retested and got this error:

> - chunk delimiter was invalid

So examined the SVNserver log:

> - Error writing base64 data: APR does not understand this error code  [500, #620018]
> - Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
> - A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #620018]

We can recreate the above 100% of the time.

---

## TRIED:

From here we tried:

Upgraded OpenSSL to latest version. Resulted in same errors above.

Copied the REPO to a new REPO to ensure no file corruption. Resulted in same errors above.

Installed SVNserver locally and tested taking network our of the equation. Resulted in same error above.

We think this may be isolated to the version of OpenSSL we are using with some other component installed with VisualSVN.

Anyone aware of this issue and how to resolve it ?

---

## COMPONENTS/SETTING:

- Windows 2008 Server R2
- Apache Subversion 1.7.6
- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.22
- OpenSSL 0.9.8x
- Neon 0.29.6
- Serf 1.0.0
- SQLite 3070603
- ZLib 1.2.3
- VisualSVN 2.5.6
- SSL enabled
- Windows 7 x64 pro client nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Nod32 installed? If yes then disabling protocol filtering can help. Best solution is to add exception for SVN.

Nod32 -> Advanced setup -> Web and email -> Protocol filtering -> Excluded applications -> check you client, mine is TortoiseProc.exe

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how to disable protocols? I have the "chunk delimiter was invalid" on a Windows environment. And I suspected the problem is Nod32. I tried disabling Stealth mode, situation is better but not solved.

Comment: Updated answer, explanation was rather vague before, sorry ;)

Answer (score 2):

The real error is `Too many open files [500, #24]`. I assume you're using *nix based Subversion server. In this case increase number of open file descriptor with the `ulimit` command:

> ulimit -n 99999

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/48717/practical-maximum-open-file-descriptors-ulimit-n-for-a-high-volume-system

Comment: The user running the process may also have a restricted number of open files, be sure to check this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ivan / Michael. Would it be possible please to indicate which file I need to add/amend ?  Have tried adding "ulimit -n 99999" to C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\conf\httpd-custom.CONF but VisualSVNServer service then fails to start.

Comment: Note its a windows server , link provided is linux solution.

Comment: @scott_lotus The path you provided from SVNServer log (/usr/site/svnrep/impc/db/revs/16122) is definitely *nix path.

Comment: @Ivan my fault, sorry that error was cut from another post , very sorry for the confusion. Will update the above errors.

Comment: @scott_lotus Ok. Do you have any other errors on server side? What http library used on the client (serf or neon)? Try run svnadmin verify command to check repository.

Comment: @Ivan. Thanks again for response. I clear out the VisualSVN Server event log. Then checkout my project. Error occurs. Check the log: 1) Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]  2) A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #620018] 3) Error writing base64 data: APR does not understand this error code  [500, #620018]. Thats all i get server side. Client side using Subversion: first SSL error above, so disabled ssl, chunk delimiter was invalid.

Comment: @scott_lotus Did you find any errors in your repository using svnadmin verify command? I recommend you contact with VisualSVN Support Team to resolve this issue (support@visualsvn.com).

Comment: Talking to support. Thanks for your help. Will post any findings.

Comment: @Ivan Zhakov - not tried yet sorry but thank you for the reply. Will update post when we progress.  SVNsupport say: 1) I strongly advise you to do the 'dump'/'load' cycle and attempt to reproduce the behavior with the new repository. 2) Have you tried to issue 'svnadmin verify' and 'svnadmin recover'. Working around the error until we can try the above.